# How to change Document Root with Docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker. I'm trying to change Document Root for my app.
my-app directory has my php codes.

**Tree**

```
Project
 - docker-compose.yml
 - html
    - my-app
 - php
    - 000-default.conf
    - Dockerfile
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  php:
    build: ./php/
    # image: php:7.2-apache
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    ports: 
      - 8080:80
    container_name: php7.2
    restart: always
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install vim
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/my-app
 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 
    EnableSendfile off
</VirtualHost>
```

I command `docker-compose up -d --build`, however document root never change to my-app where I expect. I confirmed `000-default.conf` has changed by COPY inside of container.

Please give me same advice.
Thanks.

Comment: WORKDIR keyword

Comment: I had typo only on this question.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have your ports back-to-front. In your `docker-compose.yml` file, you've set host port 8080 and container port 80 () but your v-host is listening on container port 8080.

I'm not actually seeing any reason for you to override the default site config nor for you to have a `Dockerfile` at all. The default site serves content from `/var/www/html` over container port 80 so you don't need to change that.

Try this config instead

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  php:
    image: php:7.2-apache
    volumes:
      - "./html:/var/www/html"
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
```

Run the stack using

```sh
docker-compose up -d
```

then open `http://localhost:8080/my-app/` in your browser.